# Unable to set up my web development environment with Apache in OS X 10.11 El Capitan

Tags: apache, osx-elcapitan

I have done the following things.

1) created the following conf file in /etc/apache2/users

```
`<Directory "/Users/whoami/Sites/">
 AllowOverride All
 Options +Indexes +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
 Require all granted
 Require local
 </Directory>`
```

2)Enabled the following modules

```
`LoadModule authz_host_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_host.so
 LoadModule authz_core_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_core.so
 LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
 LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_vhost_alias.so
 Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
 Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`
```

3)Edited httpd-userdir.conf by uncommenting 
`Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf`

4) restarted apache

Under Sites, i have example1 which has index.html and main.js

While accessing http://localhost/~dhavalshownkani/example1/index.html, I get a 403 error in the console. But i can see the static HMTL content.

http://localhost/Users/dhavalshownkani/Sites/example1/main.js -->403 error

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I configured the Virtual hosts file with the help of this http://digitalshore.io/local-web-development-environment-apache-osx-10-11-el-capitan/ guide. This solved my problem :)